# Making retro game music creepy

Tags: effects

I want to take some early  90s video game music and make it creepy and scary to play for haloween. I have done stuff with  sonic fames on the genesis like slowing down the carnival level and mixing three copies of the channel where one tracks pitch os raised 2 semitone one -2 and another -4. I haved used thos three track pitch alyer method woth echo amd reverb algorithms. It seems they get a semi creepy aound but they often sound noisey especially when mixing multiple tracks. My question is how can i make level and sfx of video games creepy?

Comment: For migration to SD please Tim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creepy is my middle name.

Here are some suggestions:

Regarding noise, if you have any noise on the original tracks, it will be difficult to remove it and this gets worse if you add multiple tracks with noise.

Best to have the best recordings you can get your hands on before processing.

Also learn to adjust and mix multiple tracks before doing this so you get an idea of how important it is to drop gain on each track as you add another track. Also, include some ability to analyze and apply EQ will help in your mixing.

Processes I recommend for creepy.

You already mentioned detuning one track with 2 semi tones, try 1/2 a semitone or micro tone or at least one semi tone off as the closer these are the more dissonant they will be.

Other processes:
Are you familiar with a ring modulator? Read up on it, and see if you have a friend with one built into his/hers guitar pedal. This is like the detuning thing but more intense as you add upper and lower sidebands based on the addition and subtraction of a carrier wave. Most ring modulators now a days will supply a tunable carrier.

Backwards, record your sounds in backwards mode. You can use Audacity to do this.

Reverb before sound. This works well with voice. Record your voice or sounds, then take this copy and play it backwards into a reverb process. Then take the last version and reverse it once more. The effect is to hear your voice forward but you hear the reverb part of your voice before you hear your voice.

Extreme drop in pitch. If you wanted your voice to sound like you are a death metal voice drop it 1 to 2 octaves. Many guitar pedals have this feature, otherwise Audacity might be the answer, after all it's a free download.

Vocoder: You may not have access to one of these but if you do it can be very creepy, especially with voice. This allows you to take a carrier signal and filter with your own vocal formants. See article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocoder

A more practical and cheaper way to do this:
http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/Vocoder

Comment: Thanks lor of the fIlters are for vlice and not music. Which r good for music and which for sfx

Comment: What do you mean by play the recording backwards into the reverb? Do you mean ? Do you mean to record and duplicate you audio and reverse it and then reverb it? And then duplicate it again and reverb it more?

Comment: Record voice first, then make a reverse copy while adding reverb, then take this copy and reverse it once more. You only need to add reverb once, during the part where you make the first reverse copy.

Comment: It sounds cool with some of the stuff o troed sp far. But i  am having trouble making it creepy in a video game music and this far only some of the sfx from sonic r able to be creepy. shoukd i expand my range of sfx and possibly music from retrp games on the sega till i can imagine what will be creepy

Comment: Do you play any instruments? Like Flute, or Oboe, or Piano, or Sax? Almost all instruments are capable of making creepy sounds in the hands of creative players. Here's an example of creepy piano, thunder drums, springs, sheet metal, and so on I made last summer on this video:https://vimeo.com/47605517

Comment: I only played the snare and failed at sax in band. I got some sfx like sirems and used a echo amd gverb on it amd them paulsteched it 10 seconds long amd reversed it... That  came the erie monster sound. I used the desert level from sonic n knuckles the door opening and the stomp if the robot boss of the level to sound like the doors the monsters caged in is opeming and u hear his thomps or stomps closer and closer and the a differemt sonic sfx plays when the second door effect plays and opens